# Is this authentication and encryption solution secure?

Tags: authentication

I need to communicate over insecure TCP sockets where SSL/TLS is not available. Does the following solution provide a secure means of authentication and encryption?

-

1. **Client sends: username**
2. Server generates a random token (31 bytes).
3. Server retrieves a password salt and hash (bcrypt) from the database for the given username.
4. Server encrypts the random token by the password hash.
5. **Client receives: passwordSalt + encryptAes(token, passwordHash)**
6. Client gets the passwordHash by using bcrypt on the password and the received password salt.
7. Client gets the token by decrypting the encrypted token with the password hash.
8. Client generates a random 'validation' salt (15 bytes).
9. Client generates a hash of the token using the validation salt and encrypts it with the token.
10. **Client sends: encryptAes(validationSalt + md5(token + validationSalt), token)**
11. Server gets the hash by decrypting it with the token.
12. Server compares if the received hash is equal to md5(token). If they are the same, the client has authenticated.
13. Server generates a hash of the password hash using the validation salt, pads it with 15 random bytes, and encrypts it with the token.
14. **Client receives: encryptAes(randomBytes(15) + md5(passwordHash + validationSalt), token)**
15. Client gets the hash by decrypting it with the token.
16. Client compares the hash with md5(passwordHash + validationSalt). If they are the same, the server has authenticated.

All data will now be encrypted with the token generated by the server.

-

The server is in Java, the clients are in C++ (UE4).

Public key encryption is currently not available.

-

Is there any flaw or weakness in this solution?

Comment: I understand that TLS may be complex to implement on some devices, but why isn't public key encryption an option?

Comment: It simply isn't implemented yet on the client side. I can't use libraries like boost, because then I won't be able to export to HTML5, Android, PS4, etc. I could try to implement RSA for example myself, but I don't know enough about RSA to make my own implementation, and I can't find any examples for C++ that would work together with Java.

Comment: Zwarmapapa - the original formatting was confusing. I tried to fix it without changing the meaning of your question. Please [edit your question](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/117405/edit) if you feel I changed the meaning or somehow made your question less clear.

Comment: One thing i can see is bruteforce on  validationSalt + bcrypt(token, validationSalt) or at bcrypt(passwordHash, validationSalt)

Comment: The token is already known for the client and server at step 10 and 13, would it perhaps be better if I encrypted those messages?

Comment: Lets say at Step 13 we bruteforce and recover the passwordhash by some dictionary attack. Using the recovered hash attacker can be able to decrypt secret token captured from Step 5 traffic. Thereafter can eavesdrop on further communications.

Comment: @Zwarmapapa Have you looked at/tried libraries like OpenSSL? Nobody is expected to implement TLS on their own these days... It's supported on most platforms and for the web you can readily use HTTPS/WSS with some abstraction layer.

Comment: @Sravan how can you do a dictionary attack on passwordHash? The passwordHash could be anything, unless you do a dictionary attack on bcrypt(bcrypt(password, passwordSalt), validationSalt), which would be quite expansive? But I guess it would be possible, so I'll change step 10 and 13 to them being encrypted by the generated token.

Comment: @billc.cn I can't use libraries, unless I can copy paste them in, or unless they are already made using the UE4 C++ libraries only, otherwise I can't port it to every platforms supported by the engine.

Comment: @Zwarmapapa. For example i can take 1000 worst passwords and get MD5 or SHA hash of them. So i have 1000 worst password hashes. I know the validationSalt which got transmitted in plaintext.I can try these 1000 password hashes+validationSalt  to match  bcrypt(passwordHash, validationSalt). I liked the solution.. Its a nice one..

Comment: According to the very brief research I've done, it appears that [OpenSSL is already a module in UE4](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?62473-Networking-What-is-everyone-using-for-SSL-TLS-connections&p=247991&viewfull=1#post247991).  May be worth investigating further.

Comment: @Xander Ah, it doesn't come with the engine unless you use the source build. I tried looking for it, but couldn't find it. Now I know why. --- Hmm, did some research, apparently it's not really supported for users, they only put it in the engine for internal use, like to support https requests. Using it may cause problems with newer engine versions.

Comment: @Zwarmapapa Ah, that's unfortunate.

Comment: The only downside of this seems to be that bcrypt in step 10 and 14 seem useless. The token is never known publicly, and the hashes only exist for validation. Maybe it's better to use something more efficient there, like md5?

Comment: Please keep long conversations in chat. Also, this question seems off topic.

Comment: Found out the length of the token has to be a multiple of 16 minus 1 (so 32-1 = 31), otherwise you can detect a (more likely to be) correct and incorrect decryption of AES, meaning you could make brute forcing a lot easier by doing this: decryptAes(encryptedToken, bcrypt([brute force], passwordSalt) == 30 bytes.

Comment: Hm, it's weak to a man in the middle attack, the token at step 5 can be bruteforced by using step 10 as validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically created a shared secret authentication scheme here.

However, you did not define what your security goals are. Entity authentication, strong entity authentication, confidentiality, anonymity, ...? So it's hard to say "(yes/no), this is (not) secure". If your security goals were none of the above, this is probably secure. But I wouldn't use this thing (hope you don't mind)! :-)

You seem to assume that the authentication key is the password. However, this is not the case as knowing the hash from the database is sufficient to successfully authenticate. Try it out and play the client which only knows the password hash and you will see that it works.

The problem here is that you didn't specify what exactly the secret is. Knowing that you can make the whole process much simpler.
Assume the secret is the hash from the database and you want to authenticate the user to the server:

- Server generates a session key and a random number, encrypts both with the secret and sends it to the client
- The client generates the shared secret by asking for the password
- The client decrypts the session key
- The client adds 1 to the random number, encrypts it with the session key and sends it back to the server

As you can see the security still relies on knowing the hash from the database, but setting up a shared secret and authenticating the client has become much simpler. **Please note that this is still far from secure!** I only wanted to show that things are often not what they seem. Fiddling around with salts doesn't make things necessarily better.

The point is: Complicated does not mean secure, and - as pointed out before - do not trust you self-made crypto ;-)

**Edit**: Just for the record, think about oracles, chosen protocol attacks, reflection attacks, ... get yourself used to these things and try find attacks against your own protocol. Makes fun and you will learn a lot.

Comment: Won't your given example be weak against replay attacks from the server for example? How do you know the server is the actual server? Anyway, I like the tips and help, but saying "it's probably not secure" doesn't really help me that much :P In order to know what I'm doing wrong I'd need something a bit more specific, like "x is wrong because x can do x". Anyway, the hash from the database is indeed the secret, and both sides being able to trust each other is the goal. Also, didn't know this had an official name, I'll try looking up some examples of shared secret authentication schemes.

Comment: +1 for the [pass the hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash) notification.

Comment: @Zwarmapapa "being able to trust each other" would indicate you want mutual authentication. Please excuse me not writing things down more specifically but analyzing your construct is just beyond scope. Check out e.g. "Protocols for Authentication and Key Establishment" which is available via google books online (partly) to get an understanding of the basic principles first.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution could be affected by the following concepts:

**Do-it-yourself Cryptography**

DIY crypto is an anti-pattern of secure software design. Most (>99%) attempts will fail. Nevertheless I respect your try! :-)
For example: Don't reveal the "passwordSalt", if you don't need to. It helps the attacker to crack the challenge. After one request an attacker knows the salt and has a challenge which could be cracked. The security relies only on a strong password. The attacker can crack the password offline. This should not be the case for online services. I rate this as highly insecure.

**[Perfect Forward Secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)**

The key for the encryption (serverside generated token) should be calculated on both sides (client and server) using Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange or similar. If someone recorded the traffic and gets the user password, he is able to decrypt the token and then decrypt the whole traffic, afterwards.

**Steps 13-16 not needed**

If the client can decrypt "passwordSalt + encryptAes(token, passwordHash)" successfully, the server had to know "passwordHash", therefore the user password.

This list is not complete, as several other weaknesses could be present.

Comment: Salts are not designed to be secret, and exposing them is not equivalent to storing unsalted password hashes.

Comment: You are right, but it makes it easier.

Comment: While your statement about salt is incorrect, your PFS statement is insightful.

Comment: I will try to fix that.

Comment: @honze - the whole point of salt is to provide protection once the password hash (with the salt) is stolen. If salt doesn't provide protection here, then the password hash was not complex enough (or the password was a very common one, in which case an online attack has a chance of success).

Comment: I see the point.

Comment: Your update made it look much better. Especially mentioning the weak password flaw.

Comment: At step 5, what if a packet of the server gets read and later resend? The client will be able to get the token then, while the sender is not actually the server.

Comment: Doesn't the client require the passwordSalt either way? Without it, the client won't be able to make a passwordHash, and thus won't be able to authenticate? Besides that, aren't password salts only meant to prevent rainbow tables, and nothing more than that?

Comment: OK, didn't see this one. This is a replay attack. So you would have to include a timestamp. If you do the steps 13-16 (12-15 previous) it gets better, but the security relies on insecure steps before. So it could work, but could also go wrong.

Comment: But a 30 byte random token has how much chance of ever being the same? A timestamp is only 8 bytes (a long), and this is different every millisecond and will have enough possibilities to last till year 292278994. Even UUIDs are only 16 bytes, and they are considered to always be unique. Besides that, clients will only be allowed to login 20 times every 30 minutes, after that it will automatically fail. Getting a token collision and thereby getting a successful client-side replay attack is very, very small.

Comment: If the server is using a replay attack, the client doesn't actually give away any data, it only sends the token it received from the server and a validation salt that was just randomly generated. The only one sending somewhat sensitive data is the server at step 14 (passwordHash), but the server only does this after the client has been authenticated successfully, which could never happen if the client did a replay attack. Besides that, in order to get the passwordHash, you need the server generated token, which you can only get by having the passwordHash in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Your trying to recreate a wheel, and unless your background is in cryptography it's also likely to not be a great as your intent.

Your goal is to send encrypted data from a Server to a client with the limitation that a PKI cannot exist yet. The short is we are limited to Symmetric Key's right?

Their are two rough approaches that you can consider:

**Pre-Shared key:**

[Pre-Sharred keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-shared_key) are generated and set in the client and Server and used as a common key for encryption and decryption. Your encryption of data can be secured quite well this way, but you deal with the maintenance of a PSK.

**Key Derivation Function:***
[Key Derivation Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) work under a similar principal as PSK's but they are generated on the client and server at the start of a session. The data is shared data between the two systems to generate a secret value which can be used to encrypt and decry pt systems.

Both Java and C,C++ have libraries which can build these functions.